My one-liner 'delete old files' command finds the right files but will not delete them
This command correctly finds all files in the directory that are older than 1 day:
$ find /Users/[me]/test -type f ! -newermt -1day | xargs -0 -n1
/Users/[me]/test/1.txt
/Users/[me]/test/2.txt

However, when I change the 'xargs' parameter to delete them it throws an error:
$ find /Users/[me]/test -type f ! -newermt -1day | xargs -0 rm
rm: /Users/[me]/test/2.txt
/Users/[me]/test/1.txt
: No such file or directory

Anyone know what the problem is and how to fix it?
Or maybe there's a better way of doing this? (I'm not very familiar with the macos command line, as you can probably tell!)

I think if you're going to use the -0 option w/ xargs, you must pair that with the print0 option in find; i.e. find /Users/[me]/test -type f ! -newermt -1day print0 | xargs -0 rm.  But  this may depend on which version of find & xargs you use; i.e. the native FreeBSD-derived macOS version, OR the GNU version that you'd have if you've installed (for example) MacPorts findutils. If you have a lot of files to delete, xargs is more efficient than using the delete option in find.

@Seamus macOS find seems to support -print0 but if you have GNU find, you might as well use -exec rm {} + which should be at least as efficient as xargs.

@terdon - I don't know if it's a recent addition, but GNU find also supports -delete.

find can delete directly.
find /Users/[me]/test -type f ! -newermt -1day -delete


It can also list directly, so you can run find /Users/[me]/test -type f ! -newermt -1day -ls to make sure it's going to act on the correct things.

If your version of find lacks a -delete primary (which is not part of the POSIX specification), you can also use -exec rm {} +. (Which it shouldn't; I forgot this was not unix.stackexchange.com, and the BSD version of find that ships with macOS does support -delete.)

Yes, as @Mark says, it is smart to run a "just list them" version before running the "delete them" version, so you can verify that your intentions are being manifest accurately. :)

While there are alternative flags to find such as -delete and -print0, to answer the question of what the problem is with xargs and how to fix that problem…
xargs -0 expects the null character to separate arguments.
find outputs results separated by a new line.
Therefore xargs see the result of find as
/Users/[me]/test/2.txt\n/Users/[me]/test/1.txt
#                     ^^ new line

which is one argument.
rm tries to remove the one file with that name (containing a new line), which you can think of as executing
rm "/Users/[me]/test/2.txt\n/Users/[me]/test/1.txt"

(where \n would be a new line) which it cannot find.
Remove -0 from xargs to split on new line so it executes
rm "/Users/[me]/test/2.txt" "/Users/[me]/test/1.txt"

Or, to make this more robust and able to handle arbitrary file names, including those that might have a \n in the file name itself, use
find /Users/[me]/test -type f ! -newermt -1day -print0 | xargs -0 -rm


Alternatively you may add -print0 to find arguments. It will allow to actually delete files with new line in name.

While removing the -0 works in this case, it does not work in the general case.  Try this sequence and see why:  touch foo$'\n'bar; find . -name 'foo*bar' | xargs stat  Adding -print0 to find and -0 to xargs ala talex will get the desired result.

This answer was to explain the behaviour of xargs. Alternative answers exist as I acknowledge in the answer that modify the invocation of find instead, feel free to upvote those as I have done. Thanks for your contribution!

Source of the problem explained in @grg answer. Here is alternative solution:
You need to add -print0 to find arguments.
find /Users/[me]/test -type f ! -newermt -1day -print0 | xargs -0 rm


Strong agree.  The benefit of the find -print0 | xargs -0 foo is that even if the filename has a newline in it (people and programs do crazy things sometimes--accidentally or maliciously) the foo program will always get the correct argument.

Yep, but there's no point in using xargs if you aren't even parallelizing it, so just have find do the work, either using -delete or using find ... -exec rm {} \;
